# can i parse xml file including : or / using c#

Tags: c#, xml

Can I parse a file including `:` or `/` using C# ?

This error appears:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System..Exception' occurred in System..dll

Additional information: The `/` character, hexadecimal value `0x2F`, can be included in a name.

When I parse this file:

```
<profile>
    <mini>
        <Album URI="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Album">
            <predicate queryType="getObjects">http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract</predicate>
            <predicate queryType="getObjects">http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist</predicate>
            <predicate queryType="getObjects">http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre</predicate>
            <predicate queryType="getObjects">http://dbpedia.org/ontology/producer</predicate>
            <predicate queryType="getObjects">http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate</predicate>
        </Album>
       </mini>
</profile>
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to parse the xml? "System..dll" in an exception looks strange.

Comment: Can you please write down the full exception information?

Comment: var elements = XMLDoc.Root.Elements("mini").Elements(advanceType).Elements("predicate");

Comment: Parses fine for me in PowerShell; since C# uses the same parser I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: is it necessary for an xml file to start with <?xml version="1.0"?>  ?

Comment: This Loads just fine eith XElement. Show the code and exact errormessage. Don't comment, edit the question.

Comment: @Mira, please show the code that causes the exception **and** code that you use to create/load "XMLDoc". It is impossible to answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem in  your xml, below code works

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = xDoc.Descendants("Album")
    .Select(n => new
    {
        Album = n.Attribute("URI").Value,
        Predicates = n.Elements("predicate").Select(p=>p.Value).ToArray()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LINQ2XML** to parse the XML.

```
XElement xel = XElement.Load(filePath);
//you can even load the XML from a string/stream etc also....

if (xel != null)
{
    foreach (var mini in xel.Elements("mini"))
    {
        foreach (var album in mini.Elements("Album"))
        {
            string attrValue = album.Attribute("URI").Value;
            foreach (var predicate in album.Elements("predicate"))
            {                          
                string content = predicate.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if there were another `Album` tag. if you copy it  you will see 20 predicates in the output(instead of 10).

Comment: @L.B: Ofcourse this will work. That is why i used `foreach`. It will handle any number of `mini` elements, any number of 'Albums` element and any number of  `predicate` elements.

Comment: @L.B: Yea. You are correct. Actually i used the min variable instead of album in one place. Also Elements is the correct method to use instead of Descendents as Elements give you only Direct child. Corrected my answer now. Thanks jumping in.  :)

Comment: Now remove all `.ToList()`s from your code. You won't see any difference. Then what is the use of them?

Comment: Now we can simplify it further, your outer two foreach loop can be replaced with a single `foreach (var album in xel.Descendants("Album"))`

Comment: what if there are multiple mini ?

Comment: Not a problem, since you are collecting values from `Albums` and its descendants

Comment: And finally where is `Linq`, you only use old plain `foreach`s. (I don't say it is bad;  just because you said "`You can use **LINQ2XML**`")